# Creating subcolumns at the TOP of a table

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can use CSS/HTML to divide the first line of a table, as shown below:

[image]

I know that if I wanted them to be on the bottom, I could use something like:

```
.subcol{
width: 180 px;
}
```

to do it, but I can't seem to find any way to make the subcolumns appear at the top, rather than the bottom.  Right now I am attempting to use this:

```
.col1{
float: left;
width: 795px;
padding-right:15px;
```

}

```
.col2{
float: left;
width: 320px;
}
```

and then, I use DIV to put it together:

```
<div class="col1">VIDEO></div>
<div class="col2">TEXT BOX</div>
```

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's the opposite: you create a cell that will span 2 columns, not split a cell in two. It's made with **`colspan`** attribute (same exists vertically with `rowspan`).

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/nFGYq/

**IMPORTANT note:** why are you using a table layout in the first place? You should never do that. Use `div` or other elements and style them with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Video</td>
        <td>Small text box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Text and pictures</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed; /* will force browsers to stick to widths you want, not adapt to the content of various cells as usual */
    width: 400px;
}
tr:first-child td {
    width: 120px; /* 120 + 40 + 40 = 200 */
}
td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I am using CSS/DIV

In my CSS I specified the size of the columns, then use <div class="col1"> and <div class="col2"> to put them into the right place.  But right now my columns go all the way down, and I want them to end at the first line.

Comment: Please post your code in your question then (HTML and more complete CSS)

Answer (score 0):

you can use table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>video</td>
<td>small text box</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>text and picture</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I already have the CSS set up partially.  Right now, I have this: code

Answer (score 0):

If you have the area divided up into divs, you just need to change the order of which they are in HTML -- you can place to the two areas on top, then place a clearing div under them, so the text and pictures shows below both (and clears the floats).